# Kendo - data-bind onclick works on web, not on mobile

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, click

I'm relatively new to Kendo and Javascript, so I may be overlooking something obvious...

I have a list entry with a simple call in it as follows:

```
<li style="margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0">
                    <a href="#transaction-details" data-bind="click: onBadTransaction">
                        <span style="float:left; vertical-align:middle"><img src="styles/images/X_Red_24.png" /></span>
                        <span style="margin-left:3%; vertical-align:auto; font-weight:bold">$21.36</span>
                        <span style="margin-left:3%; vertical-align:auto; font-size:14px;">Starbucks #556734</span>
                        <span style="float:right; padding-right:1.5em; font-size:small">12:37pm</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

When I click this element via my browser, it executes as expected. However, when I load it on my mobile, it does not.

The function is just changing a variable state from True to False.

I'm using this same function call on other elements and it works fine, so I know the javascript is good... It's just not working on the list item on mobile only (again, works find on PC web browser).

Any ideas why this works on web, but not mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you can not use both redirection(a href) and data-bind:click simultaneously.

Instead do the redirection in the onBadTransaction() function.